# import dmp file failed in oracle[ORA-31685,ORA-39083,ORA-01932,ORA-31684]

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

***What am I doing***

I have been given a UAT env., dmp file for local database setup.I followed the procedure described [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/datapump_OBE/datapump.html).

***Errors***

The below are the errors I am getting, seems like my local username is missing some roles which I am unable to figure out. I did granted ADMIN/DBA privilege to 'SYSTEM' user though.

```
Master table "SYSTEM"."UAT" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."UAT":
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-31685: Object type USER:"SYSTEM" failed due to insufficient privileges. Failing sql is:
ALTER USER "SYSTEM" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'DABD3C3A967782B6' DEFAULT TABLESPACE "UAT01" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP01"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'CONNECT'
Failing sql is:
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "SYSTEM"
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'RESOURCE'
Failing sql is:
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "SYSTEM"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
ORA-31685: Object type DEFAULT_ROLE:"SYSTEM" failed due to insufficient privileges. Failing sql is:
ALTER USER "SYSTEM" DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT", "RESOURCE"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
ORA-31685: Object type TABLESPACE_QUOTA:"SYSTEM" failed due to insufficient privileges. Failing sql is:
DECLARE   TEMP_COUNT NUMBER;   SQLSTR VARCHAR2(200); BEGIN   SQLSTR := 'ALTER USER "SYSTEM" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "UAT01"';  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTR;EXCEPTION   WHEN OTHERS THEN    IF SQLCODE = -30041 THEN       SQLSTR := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLESPACES               WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = ''UAT01'' AND CONTENTS = ''TEMPORARY''';      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTR INTO TEMP_COUNT;      IF TEMP_COUNT
```

After providing the CONNECT,RESOURCE roles to system user WITH admin option, I am getting below errors.

[SYSTEM USER WITH ROLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zutsJ.jpg)

```
Master table "SYSTEM"."IMPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_101" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."IMPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_101":  
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-39083: Object type USER failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'UAT01' does not exist
Failing sql is:
ALTER USER "SYSTEM" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'DABD3C3A967782B6' DEFAULT TABLESPACE "UAT01" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP01"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE_QUOTA failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'UAT01' does not exist
Failing sql is:
DECLARE   TEMP_COUNT NUMBER;   SQLSTR VARCHAR2(200); BEGIN   SQLSTR := 'ALTER USER "SYSTEM" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "UAT01"';  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTR;EXCEPTION   WHEN OTHERS THEN    IF SQLCODE = -30041 THEN       SQLSTR := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TABLESPACES               WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = ''UAT01'' AND CONTENTS = ''TEMPORARY''';      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTR INTO TEMP
```

Thanks all in Advance !!

Comment: System should already be a superuser, no need to grant anything to the user "System".  What username are you using to do the import and what role and privileges have you granted to that user?

Comment: I am using system user to import.

Comment: Do you know what version of Oracle the dmp file came from and what version of Oracle are you importing the file to?  Some objects need to exist prior to importing the file, for example the `UAT01` tablespace.  Create the tablespace manually and I believe the file will import.

Comment: UAT01 Version - Oracle Database 11g -11.2.0.4.0-64 bit || SYSTEM version - 11.2.0.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create all needed tablespaces before importing the dump. The dump import does not create physical files needed by the database

Comment: Exactly!! also figured it out that needed to grant roles CONNECT,RESOURCE,IMP_FULL_DATABASE with ADMIN OPTION and also DEFAULT_ROLE